# Heatsink compatibility for the new Intel Skylake processors (LGA1151)

Tags: cpu, fan, compatibility, cooling, heatsink

The new Intel Skylake processors have just released, but they don't come with a fan/heatsink. As a result, I have to purchase a third party heatsink, but it seems there are none yet listed on popular sites that support LGA1151.

I hear a lot of speculation that older LGA socket heatsinks are compatible with the new LGA 1151, but I would like some confirmation on this.

Are previous heatsinks compatible with the new LGA1151 socket?

Comment: Unless you are getting a k series, or OEM tray, it will come with a heatsink just like the old ones.

Comment: Nope, I already purchased two (i5 and i7) and like I said, Intel decided not to provide heatsinks. They do not come with them. I already solved this though. I purchased a really nice Noctua CPU heatsink. Love it

Answer (score 14, accepted):

LGA115x heatsinks are compatible.

From source 3:

> Noctua's [info sheet for their new NH-D15S cooler](http://www.noctua.at/pdf/infosheets/noctua_nh_d15s_datasheet_en.pdf), stating it's **compatible with LGA 1151** (Skylake), and the [installation manual](http://www.noctua.at/pdf/manuals/noctua_nh_d15s_manual_en.pdf), which shows using the same design of rigid, nonadjustable backplate with fixed posts as for the current 1150/5/6, with no special instructions for 1151, so the mobo holes and socket height must match. I'd been assuming the mount would be unchanged for Skylake, but it's nice to see for sure.

Sources: [1](https://pcpartpicker.com/forums/topic/97158-will-lga1150-cpu-coolers-be-compatible-with-upcoming-skylake-socket-lga1151), [2](http://linustechtips.com/main/topic/409786-lga-1151-cooling-compatibility/), [3](http://www.silentpcreview.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=68481)

Answer (score 5):

Skylake Processors use the same mounting specifications as older LGA115X heatsinks.  In other words, heatsinks that work with LGA 1150, 1155, and 1156 will work with Skylake.

Below is an example of one such heatsink.
[image: Skylink Heatsink]